# Continues Forward Engineering with ERD/MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, erd

I'm using MySQL Workbench to forward engineer the `ERD` to my `MySQL` database. When continuing with the project I had to do some changes in the ERDs. How to do forward engineering again to reflect the ERD changes in the same mysql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Workbench has a feature called: synchronization (see `Database -> Synchronize Model`. This is a two-way merge of changes made in your ERD diagram and your MySQL server. The synchronization wizard allows you to determine what changes to take over (in which direction) and what to ignore. It's the perfect means to continously update both the model and the server.